Cannot create scheduled task that runs as a user
When I attempt to specify a user and provide password, I get an error: "Task Scheduler cannot apply your changes. The user account is unknown, the password is incorrect, or the user account does not have permission to modify the task."

Is this computer owned by your employer, on a corporate domain?

To overcome this, start Task Scheduler as an Admin
